# Why is there no std::move_n algorithm?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm assuming that there is a [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) so that this can work with input iterators.  Is there some reason why there is no `std::move_n` for the same reason?

Comment: `std::copy_n()` works with the same types of iterators as `std::copy()`.  They both take *InputIterator*s as input. The only difference is that `std::copy()` takes 2 input iterators denoting a range, whereas `std::copy_n()` takes 1 input iterator and a count. Not all situations have 2 iterators available to iterate between, sometimes a count makes more sense.

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is probably pretty mundane.

`std::copy` existed forever, it was the only one of these algorithms in C++03.

[N1377](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm) (2002) added move semantics into the language and also introduced the algorithms `std::move()` and `std::move_backward()` to mirror the existing `std::copy()` and `std::copy_backward()`. Those were the only copying algorithms in existence - so those were the only ones that got `move` versions.

[N2569](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2569.pdf) (2008) added a bunch more algorithms, most of which existed in the original Standard Template Library implementation - this is where `std::copy_n()` and `std::copy_if()` came from. Since the premise of the paper was a bunch of algorithms that have been around and used for years, it couldn't have included `std::move_n()` or [`std::move_if()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55502720/2069064). It seems that this simply wasn't considered.

I'm guessing if these happened in the opposite order, we might have had `std::move_n()` today. But at this point, it might not be worth adding. Since, `std::copy_n()` isn't even used super often and `move_n` is very easy to implement:

```
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt move_n(InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
    return std::copy_n(std::make_move_iterator(first), count, result);
}
```

Comment: What about `std::uninitialized_move` and `std::uninitialized_move_n`?

Comment: @Adrian [That proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0040r3.html) (2016) chose to cover both?

Answer (score 4):

There is a `std::make_move_iterator` to adapt any iterator into providing an rvalue.

Sending an adapted input iterator to `std::copy_n` will achieve the desired effect, without much added noise.

Comment: Then why have the `std::move` algorithm?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes there is an [algorithm `std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move)

Comment: Ultimately, I guess no one considered `move_n` a common enough operation to warrant a shorthand.

Comment: @Adrian C++ library code has a busload of overloads and near-repetitions to make the code more expressive. It is not the reason to add definitions of course.

Comment: I am not sure, but there could be still a difference between `std::move[range]` (`std::move_n`) and `std::copy` (`std::copy_n`). `std::move_n` could be conventionally marked `noexcept`. `std::move[range]` is not marked `noexcept` (I don't know why) but it could. Well maybe not because, that is true only if moves are really moves (destructive) in assignment. Which one doesn't know in advance. The point is that `std::move` and `std::move_n` could be more specific at detecting the noexceptness of the move assigment, if present.