# vector<map<string,MyObject> list inserting data in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap

I have two `vector<map<string,MyObject>>` type data and I want to move or copy some of `MyObject` data to copy another in the same type in C++ like below:

```cpp
using namespace std;

struct MyObject{
  string id;
  string name;
  string phone;
  string salary;
};

//Somewhere else have below type.
vector<map<string,MyObject>> v1;
vector<map<string,MyObject>> v2;
```

How can I perform the above-given operation?

Comment: Do you want to copy the vector? `v2=v1`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14977748/4123703. Note: `MyObject` should follow [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Edit: it follows rule of zero, which is better.

Comment: @LouisGo it's following the rule of zero, which is superior

Comment: @ Daniel Langr, i want some of them not all data of MyObject.

Comment: Elaborate on "some of them" with full code (or a bit simplified) of `MyObject`. Mostly if it follows rule of zero, copy should be handled by compiler.

Comment: when you copy some from v1 to v2, do you want to keep what was in v1 before?

Comment: @LouisGo,I meant like name,phone only or name,salary only.

Comment: Partially copy could be done by full copy and partial erase. You may use a lambda to erase unwanted data. If you have performance issue, elaborate on your "full" context.

Comment: @codepro123 I would then prefer having a member function so call `MyObject& MyObject::copyNamePhone(const  MyObject& rhs)` rather than overloading the copy or move ctor. This will allow the compiler to still provide usual/ normal copy-move ctor.

Comment: @Const,Yes I already have member function but what after that how can i traversed and copy or move?

Comment: Take a look at [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), if you may use C++17 or above. Or simply `v2.reserve(v1,size())` and `emplace` to prevent multiple copy.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example, I change type to `std::vector<Myobject>` instead of your complext vector of map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using std::string;
    using std::vector;

    struct MyObject {
        string id;
        string name;
        string phone;
        string salary;

        MyObject copyidname() {
            MyObject obj{ id, name, "","" };
            return obj;
        }
    };
    // Simplifiled type to demonstrate copy
    vector<MyObject> v1;
    v1.push_back( MyObject{ "1","1","1","1" });
    vector<MyObject> v2;

    // Set capacity to prevent reallocation.
    v2.reserve(v1.size());
    for (auto it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); ++it) {
        v2.push_back(it->copyidname());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provide any constructor to `MyObject`, [compiler will generate necessary move-copy constructors for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi).

So no worries, just do

```
v2 = v1;
```

for copy

```
v2 = std::move(v1);
```

for move

---

For the conditional copy you can use [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) algorithum from `<algorithm>` header.

For the conditional move (move_if) you can modify the above algorithm like shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55502720/why-is-there-no-stdmove-if-algorithm) :

```
template <class InputIt, class OutputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
OutputIt move_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    return std::copy_if(std::make_move_iterator(first), std::make_move_iterator(last),
        d_first, pred);
}
```

Comment: ,I want only some of the parameter of MyObject structure, not all

Comment: @codepro123 then you do [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with condition for conditional copy, and [`move_if` like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55502720/why-is-there-no-stdmove-if-algorithm)

Comment: @Const Does `std::copy_if` allow conditional class member copy? Maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: @LouisGo It will copy the entire class member, not some of them. If OP needs only some members in the struct to be copied, he needs to implement those constructors as per.